# Flutter ListView wrong scroll gesture direction (not scroll direction) inside a RotatedBox

Tags: listview, dart, flutter

I'm currently implementing a ListView in Flutter, the problem happens when putting ListView inside a RotatedBox, the scroll direction and axis is not updated semantically when there's a rotation:

for example, this is a pure LTR horizontal listview:

```
ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemExtent: 320,
  itemCount: _categories.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return CategoryWidget(_categories[index]);
  },
)
```

If putting inside a RotatedBox, rotated 180 deg, I should expect the scroll direction to be updated as well, but it is kept the same as non-rotated, making it scroll oppositely to the gesture direction:

```
RotatedBox(
  quarterTurns: 2,
  child: ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemExtent: 320,
    itemCount: _categories.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return CategoryWidget(_categories[index]);
    },
  )
)
```

This problem persists in other cases such as using Transform.rotate() as well.

Pic: [For your information, the bottom list scrolling is natural, but the top list which is rotated 180deg, is not natural](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ7LA.png)

Comment: Why aren't you using the `reverse: true` property of the `ListView` to make the list scroll in the other direction?

Comment: @chemamolins it only reverses the order of the list items, but not the gesture direction

Comment: You can change the `scrollDirection` dynamically based on the quarter turns yourself.

Comment: @Miguel no it's not possible, as scrollDirection only accept 2 values of enum Axis, horizontal and vertical. 

For `quarterTurns = 2`, it means 180-deg rotating, so the horizontal `scrollDirection` is still the same, but gesture direction should be inverted, but there's no way to do that.

Comment: I still don't understand what exactly you are trying to achieve. Could you elaborate a little more or show an example?

Comment: @chemamolins I believe he's trying to have the scroll direction exactly in the angle of the `RotatedBox`

Comment: @chemamolins 
I have horizontal list A B C. By default, naturally if I flick the finger from right to left, of course the list will scroll from right to left.

The thing is, I need to rotate the list 180deg (its appearance). The bug is, after rotated, if I flick from right to left, the list will scroll in the opposite direction, which is not natural.

Even if I use `reverse`, I expect the scroll direction can reverse as it is described in Flutter doc, in fact, it reverses the order of the items (to be C B A), but not the scroll direction.

Comment: @chemamolins I have added the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I believed this has a related [GitHub issue ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18408). Generally, the problem focus on the effect of plane rotations on the gesture as mentioned on [the thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18408):

> I found the problem when the transformation contains out of plane
> rotations (i.e. around the x or y axis). The problem is that
> `RenderTransform.hitTestChildren` uses
> `MatrixUtils.transformPoint(inverse, position)` when hit at
> `position`, where `inverse` is the inverse of the transformation
> matrix.
>
> `MatrixUtils.transformPoint` gets a 2D-point and assumes the `z`
> coordinate is zero:
>
> ```
> static Offset transformPoint(Matrix4 transform, Offset point) {
>     final Vector3 position3 = Vector3(point.dx, point.dy, 0);
>     final Vector3 transformed3 = transform.perspectiveTransform(position3);
>     print("z_transformed = ${transformed3.z}");
>     return Offset(transformed3.x, transformed3.y);
>   }
> ```
>
> That is wrong in this case. The original child of `Transformed` is
> flat and has `z = 0`. After a transformation that contains out of
> plane rotations, `z_transformed != 0`. That `z` is ignored, as it is
> irrelevant for painting. However, when transforming back, as is the
> cases for hit testing, it should be taking into account. After the
> inverse transformation, `z = 0` should hold again, since we should
> have transformed the point back onto the `z = 0` plane. That is not
> the case, as will be evident by the print statement I added above.
>
> The correct inverse transformation has to recover the "lost"
> transformed `z` before applying the matrix. That `z` is easily found
> by using the fact that the inverse transformed `z` must be zero, that
> is, by solving `0 = A_2 * x + A_6 * y + A_10 * Z + A_14`. The proper
> inverse transform of a 2D point becomes:
>
> ```
> static Offset inverseTransformPoint(Matrix4 inverseTransform, Offset point) {
>     final A = inverseTransform.storage;
>     final Z = -(A[2]*point.dx + A[6]*point.dy + A[14])/A[10];
>     final Vector3 position3 = Vector3(point.dx, point.dy, Z);
>     final Vector3 transformed3 = inverseTransform.perspectiveTransform(position3);
>     print("z = ${transformed3.z} (should be zero)");
>     return Offset(transformed3.x, transformed3.y);
>   }
> ```
>
> I ignored the cases where `A[10] == 0` (a π/2 rotation around x or y
> axis) but that should be handled separately.
>
> (There is also an `inverseTransformRect` that, from code inspection,
> appears to have the same bug.)

I believe the issue has been closed and resolved by the PR [#32192](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/32192).